# tcpreplay how to add all pcap files under one directory to let the tcpreplay pcap files

Tags: tcpreplay

the latest tcpreplay still only support to replay a file(files).

for example the command is
tcpreplay -i eth0 sample.pcap sample1.pcap

I have over 100 pcaps that need to replay. they r all under folder is there a way to let tcpreplay plays all files under one directory ( including files from all sub-directories)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

In case there are other files:

```
tcpreplay -i eth0 *pcap
```

Or in case only pcaps are there:

```
tcpreplay -i eth0 *
```